# Node.js variables for current request only?

Tags: node.js, session, session-variables

I am very new to Node.js, and I was wondering if that, except for session(), I could use a "storage" to store variables for the current request?

I have an API which is based on an Authorization header, and a pool of valid tokens stored in Redis.

Therefore I don't have a session and don't want to.

But I would like to store variables for further use during this request. For example, I would like to store the user_id corresponding to the token found in Redis, so that I can use it wherever I want.

If I do something like:

`app = express();
app.user_id = 1;`

Is it ok, or will my user_id become global to all requests handled by the app? (in short: is the app instanciated for each request handled by the server, or is it persistent?)

If this is not ok, how could I achieve something like this without sessions?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: The `app` handles all requests, and would only be created once on startup.  When you say "wherever I want" how broad is that?  Things can be placed within the current request, but then you'd have to have access to the request to access them.

Comment: How broad? Mmmh I don't know. I'm used to sessions. I just want every controller to know the current user. Maybe I can insert into the request as you suggested, then! After looking at the doc, there does not seem to be a function for that, so maybe I will just use it as an associative array. Thank you dylants! Can you post an answer so that I can validate it?

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if that answer was what you were thinking :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `app` handles all requests, and would only be created once on startup, but `req` lives for only the lifetime of the request.  Keep in mind that the `req` in Express is just an object, and as such, can be assigned values.  So if you wanted to allow the controller to have access to some value (similar to sessions), you could do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// middleware that assigns a value '123' to 'req.user_id'
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.user_id = 123;
    next();
});

// controller which responds with the 'req.user_id'
app.get('/hello', function(req, res){
  res.send('req.user_id: ' + req.user_id);  // responds with req.user_id: 123
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

In the above example, the middleware that I created assigns a value to the request, called `user_id`.  This value lives for the life of the request.  You could do a similar thing to assign a dynamic value to the `req` so that you can access it via your controllers.

Comment: Thanks, super simple!